# Run Fetch xml report in borowser shows the Following Error

Tags: dynamics-crm

Check Report in Browser show the following error:
[image]

In Plugin show this Error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "MSCRM_CONFIG" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ---> Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: Cannot open database "MSCRM_CONFIG" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like credentials mismatch. Check your reporting service, it should run on behalf of the user who has access to Dynmaics CRM instance it is supposed to work with.